# Добавление данных в файл при условии, что данные до этого в файле отсутствовали Python

Tags: python, файлы

Пишу парсер объявлений для сайтов с арендами жилья, столкнулась с такой проблемой: несмотря на то, что информация в файле уже присутствует (т.е. ссылки на объявления), программа всё-равно их добаляет по второму разу, а нужно чтобы добавлялись только ссылки на новые объявления или не добавлялось ничего (при условии, что новых объявлений(ссылок) нету).
Как сделать так, чтобы добавлялисьь только уникальные ссылки, а не дубли?

```
flats_links_db = open('flats_links_db.txt', 'a+') #файл с ссылками


SomeSite_url = 'https://somesite.by' #сайт с объявлниями
response = requests.get(SomeSite_url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 


SomeSitе_list = soup.find('div', {'data-name' : 'lists'}) #поиск нужного блока
SomeSitе_flats_list = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'hrefs'})


for SomeSitе_flats in SomeSitе_flats_list:
    SomeSitе_flats_links = SomeSitе_flats.find('a').get('href') + '\n' #получение ссылок на обяъвления
    if SomeSitе_flats_links not in flats_links_db: #запись ссылок при условии, что этих ссылок не было ранее
        flats_links_db.write(SomeSitе_flats_links)
```

Comment: Думаю, использовать для этой цели текстовый файлик не очень хорошая затея в целом. Лучше бы вам подключить базу данных. Для этой цели хватит SQLite. Прикрутить SQLAlchemy и там уже спокойно проверять есть ли такая запись в базе или нет.

Comment: @Lida flats_links_db у вас содержит сам файл, а вам еще нужно из него забрать ссылки, например split("/n")

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце алгоритм такой: считать файл полностью (полюбому его нужно будет читать весь) и затем потроить хеш (или словарь "dict {}" в терминах питона) по ключу который должен быть уникальным. 
В процессе считывания файла проверяете есть ли уже такой ключ, и если нет то добавляете. Затем сохраняете словарь в файл, перезаписывая его. А вообще Вам бы следовало подумать в сторону баз данных для этой цели. Там и выборки имеются, и поддерживаются транзакции. Т.е. если в момент между считыванием Вашего файла и записью произойдет сбой то Ваша файловая БД будет испорчена. С сетевой БД такой неприятности не случится. В худшем случае будет отменена последняя транзакция.

Comment: @AnOtherOne с чего это вы решили, что с файловой будет сбой?

Comment: @danilshik не обязательно будет, но может быть. А с базой не будет, т.к база в случае невыполнения транзакции сделает роллбэк.

Comment: @danilshik Даже не знаю что Вам на это ответить. Вы ведь точно не вчера родились? Дерьмо случается, знаите ли, причем постоянно. Но БД это дерьмо вывозит.

Answer (score 0):

Краткий пример для понимания. Чтобы добавлять ссылку в новую строку, нужно открывать файл в режиме `a` (append). Чтобы искать в этом файле, нужно открывать файл в режиме `r` (read) и искать не в самом объекте файла, а в списке его строк, который можно получить, вызвав цепью 2 метода - `read` и `splitlines`. Но лучше бы вам использовать для этих целей базу данных, конечно.

```py
with open('test.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('some value\n')

with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    links = file.read().splitlines()
    print('some value' in links) #True
```

Comment: Добавила переменную flats_links_db_read = open('flats_links_db.txt', 'r') и в цикле заменила на if SomeSite_flats_links not in flats_links_db_read.read().splitlines() и ничего не изменилось, дубли продолжают добавляться в файл. Буду пробовать работать с БД. Спасибо.